# Moderator list: Quantum Computing missing

Tags: support, moderators

Glancing at the [moderator list](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators), I noticed that there is no entry for [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/). Is that by design or are the moderators of this site just missing?

I realize that the [moderation process](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site?cb=1) is not finished yet - but with [Robert Cartaino♦](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/robert-cartaino) there seems to be at least one moderator already.

---

Concerning the possible duplicate *[Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)*: I was not asking who they are and what their role is; just why the ones for [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) were not (yet) listed on the [Stack Exchange moderator list](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)

Comment: Relevant, but probably not a dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181383/when-should-moderator-pro-tempore-nominations-start

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Robert is not a moderator of the site. He, like all of the [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/284336), has moderation abilities network-wide.

The link will be added when the site mods are appointed. These moderators will then appear on [this page](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), which is currently blank.